# What can cause a cookie not to be set on the client?

Tags: ajax, http, cookies, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a web application that uses jQuery.ajax to perform a request to another host (right now actually the same because I'm using different ports of "localhost"). The server then returns a cookie.

The cookie value in the HTTP response as shown in Chrome's Dev Tools is

```
Set-Cookie: MyUserSession=JxQoyzYm1VfESmuh-v22wyiyLREyOkuQWauziTrimjKo=;expires=Sun, 10 Feb 2013 22:08:47 GMT;path=/api/rest/
```

and so has an expiry of 4 hours in the future.

However, the cookie does not get stored and sent with subsequent requests (tested in both Chrome and Firefox). I first thought it must be "10-Feb-2013" instead of "10 Feb 2013" but that doesn't make a difference. Chrome also shows "Expires" as "Invalid date" on the cookies tab of the response, but that might as well be a [Dev Tools bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123013).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to run your code in a web-server, e.g. not at localhost?

Comment: what language are you using to write this?

Comment: also, Assuming you're not in GMT, what time zone are you in?

Comment: I'm using [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) for the web service. My timezone is Berlin (GMT+1 currently), so that's not the problem IMO.

Comment: I also now tried with the server on an external host, same problem. Even changed the cookie to be simply "MyUserSession=TESTTEST", i.e. session expiry and no URL path restriction – still does not get stored!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Since during development, my server is at "localhost:30002" and my web app at "localhost:8003", they are considered *different* hosts regarding CORS. Therefore, all my requests to the server are covered by CORS security rules, especially [Requests with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials). "Credentials" include cookies as noted on that link, so the returned cookie was not accepted because I did not pass

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

to jQuery's `$.ajax` function. I also have to pass that option to subsequent CORS requests in order to send the cookie.

I added the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the server side and changed the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from wildcard to `http://localhost:8003` (port number is significant!). That solution now works for me and the cookie gets stored.

Comment: You saved us, my hero!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question or just part of it.

Comment: Can you give a constructive comment on _which part_ is missing that you wanted answered in a better way?

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with a similar scenario (no CORS) for hours, I found out another potential reason: **be sure to explicitly set the path for the cookie**.

My front-end app was making a call to `HOST_URL/api/members/login`, and this was returning the right `Set-Cookie` header, with no path.

I could see the cookie under `Response Cookies` in Chrome DevTools, but subsequent requests were not including it. Went to `chrome://settings/cookies`, and the cookie was there, but the path was `/api/members`.

Specifying root path when setting the cookie at server-side fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

where do you get the date from?

if you add it manually try making it failproof

```
var exdays = 3; //3 days valid as an example
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
//Now set the cookie to said exdate
document.cookie = "MyUserSession =" + escape(JxQoyzYm1VfESmuh-v22wyiyLREyOkuQWauziTrimjKo=)+"; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Good idea. I entered `document.cookie = "MyUserSession=JxQoyzYm1VfESmuh-v22wyiyLREyOkuQWauziTrimjKo=;expires=Sun, 10 Feb 2013 22:08:47 GMT;path=/api/rest/"` in the JS console and the cookie actually showed up in my cookie debugging extension. Very strange.

Comment: is it possible that you simply forgot to attach the cookie to the document in your previous code? IIRC it cannot be attached to window.cookie for example

Comment: btw it has to be `exdate.setDate(exdate.getTime() + (exhours *3600) ); //where exhours is 4 in your case` to match your desired expiration of course