# Does Angular 2 application block cookies from being stored by default?

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, angular

A developer of a backend to which I am connecting is assuring me that when he sends a cookie in `set-cookie` header that the browser should automatically save the cookie and send it back with following requests.

Does Angular 2 block cookies from being sent?

Since backend and frontend are both running on localhost, does them being on different ports block cookies from being sent with the requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a different port it's a CORS request. 
Set
on the client

```
xhr.withCredentials = true
```

See also

- [Angular 2 Http request does not send credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905399/angular-2-http-request-does-not-send-credentials)
- [Angular2 replacement of $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184049/angular2-replacement-of-httpprovider-defaults-withcredentials)

On the server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/?redirect_from_locale=de

Comment: I'm sending from localhost:5000 to localhost:5000

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sending from localhost:5000 to localhost:5000". Do you load the page from the same port where you make the HttpRequests to?

Comment: Yes. My flask backend is serving the static files for the website and responding to the requests from the same port

Comment: Actually, I don't know. Anyway, Angular isn't involved. This only a server<->browser issue. You could try a `POST` request. If it's a CORS issue the request will fail with a message containing "preflight". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801021/what-can-cause-a-cookie-not-to-be-set-on-the-client