# Spring @RestController not setting cookies with response

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, spring-restcontroller

I have the following rest endpoint that I would like to send a cookie along with my `ResponseEntity`. However after succesfully sending the response, the cookie is nowhere to be found.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myPath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createToken(HttpServletResponse response)
    final String token = "a1b2c3d4e";

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", token);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    // Return the token
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MyCustomResponse(token));
}
```

MyCustomResponse

```
class MyCustomResponse {
    private final String token;
    public MyCustomResponse(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

I have also tried creating the `ResponseEntity` manually and setting the cookie in the headers with the `"Set-Cookie"` header but same thing, no cookie.

**edit**: I have confirmed that the `Set-Cookie` header is in fact present in the response, however it is not actually being stored in the browser. I am using a static web-app running in WebStorm to access my rest endpoint running on a different port. This web app is just using JQuery's `$ajax` method to call the REST endpoint, nothing fancy. When I run the web app in WebStorm I am able to see the cookie it creates in my browser, so that confirms my browser is allowing cookie storage.

Comment: Works fine for me. Please provide a [mcve] and show us how you make the request and how you determine `Set-Cookie` is not in the response.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok so iI just figured out how to view the full response in firefox and indeed the `Set-Cookie` header is there. But when I look in the storage tab of developer tools there is no cookie.

Comment: It's there for me, after I send the request.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis perhaps im looking in the wrong place then. I am using a static web-app in intellij to access my rest endpoint running on a different port. I can see the cookie set from intellij but my cookie from the rest point isnt there

Comment: No cookies are being shown as returned by the server when I access it with Postman either

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this is weird. In both Chrome and Firefox when I examine the response, it shows that it is setting cookies. But when I go into the browser settings and search cookies it isnt there in firefox or chrome. I do not have cookies disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the browser side of things.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis check my answer if you're curious what the solution was

Comment: Nice find, you may want to add some of those comment details to your question so that others can make the link to what you mention in your answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for the advice, just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. My web application I am using to access my rest api is running on a different local port than my rest api. This causes the AJAX request to fail CORS requirements, thus the cookie doesnt actually get set.

I found the solution here [What can cause a cookie not to be set on the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801021/what-can-cause-a-cookie-not-to-be-set-on-the-client)

**edit**: I should add that it was adding the `xhrFields` snippet to JQuery's `$ajax` method that fixed it for me, the other parts weren't necessary.

**(posting the answer below in case it gets deleted)**

I think I found the solution. Since during development, my server is at "localhost:30002" and my web app at "localhost:8003", they are considered *different* hosts regarding CORS. Therefore, all my requests to the server are covered by CORS security rules, especially [Requests with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials). "Credentials" include cookies as noted on that link, so the returned cookie was not accepted because I did not pass

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

to jQuery's `$.ajax` function. I also have to pass that option to subsequent CORS requests in order to send the cookie.

I added the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the server side and changed the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from wildcard to `http://localhost:8003` (port number is significant!). That solution now works for me and the cookie gets stored.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but I'm behind AJP.