# How can I set a cookie along with the ResponseEntity using Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, cookies

There are three code snippets below. A cookie does not show up in the browser with the first two approaches. A cookie does show up in the browser with the last approach but I am looking for an approach that lets me send an arbitrary response object (like TestResponse), not just a file.

Maybe another difference to note is that I'm sending an async request using the whatwg-fetch.js library for the first two snippets but hitting the route via browser refresh in the last snippet. I need the cookie to be set by the time an async request completes.

**(Snippet 1)The below code snippet does not work as the cookie does not show up in the browser.**

```
@PostMapping(value="/test")
public ResponseEntity<TestResponse> test(@RequestBody TestReq 
    testReq, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){

    String testMessage = testReq.getTestMessage();

    TestResponse testResponse = new TestResponse();
    testResponse.setTestMessage(testMessage);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Set-Cookie", "key="+"value");

    ResponseEntity<TestResponse> testResponseEntity
        = new ResponseEntity<TestResponse>(testResponse, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    return testResponseEntity;

}
```

**(Snippet 2) This next code snippet also does not work as the cookie does not show up in the browser.**

```
@PostMapping(value="/test")
public ResponseEntity<TestResponse> test(@RequestBody TestReq 
    testReq, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){

    String testMessage = testReq.getTestMessage();

    TestResponse testResponse = new TestResponse();
    testResponse.setTestMessage(testMessage);

    ResponseEntity<TestResponse> testResponseEntity
        = new ResponseEntity<TestResponse>(testResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

    Cookie c = new Cookie("key", "value");
    res.addCookie(c);

    return testResponseEntity;

}
```

**(Snippet 3) The following code works. The cookie shows up in my browser when I load localhost.**

```
@GetMapping(value="/")
public String home(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
    Cookie c = new Cookie("key","value");
    res.addCookie(c);
    return "views/app.html;
}
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823950/spring-restcontroller-not-setting-cookies-with-response). It might be relevant, if in Response Headers `Set-Cookie` exists, then `access-control-allow-origin` is missing and you should figure out CORS issues.

Comment: You're right, Set-Cookie was in the response headers. My issue was not as complicated as the one linked though. I just needed to add "credentials: same-origin " to my fetch. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.